# l3regex usage throws __scan_new:N error

Tags: expl3, l3regex

Using TeXLive, with this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\begin{document}
  a
\end{document}
```

I get an error for an undefined control sequence

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3tl-analysis.sty
Package: l3tl-analysis 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token lists analysis
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3str.sty
Package: l3str 2013/04/24 v4482 L3 Experimental strings
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \__scan_new:N 

l.54 \__scan_new:N
                   \s__tl
```

I assume some incompatible (too old) L3 packages. However, the Debian packages word quite well in resolving dependencies in the past. Could you please assist me?

Comment: As you observe, this is a version mismatch, but not the one you think it is! A quick look at the log I get here suggests to me that you've got an incorrect version of `expl3` or part thereof. Could you add `\listfiles` to your input, miss out `\usepackage{l3regex}` and edit the `*File list*` from your log into the question?

Comment: You might also look through the log to see where `expl3` and the various `l3...` packages are loading from: my suspicion is that one or more is a 'local' file which is therefore out-of-sync with the main tree.

Comment: Adding `\listfiles` pointed me to the problem. For some reason, there was a local texmf tree. Removing it solved the problem. Thanks, Joseph.

Comment: @user39625 In that case, I'll write up something as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file versions in the question:

```
Package: l3tl-analysis 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token lists analysis
Package: l3str 2013/04/24 v4482 L3 Experimental strings
```

are both 'matching' (there should be no issues with this combination). Thus the problem must lie elsewhere. As `\__scan_new:N` is not defined I think you have an older version of `l3kernel` installed which pre-dates the introduction of the 'scan mark' approach. Thus the solution will be to check your `.log` file carefully for where `expl3` and the various component packages are loaded. They should all come from the same tree.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, if you are encountering this problem, it is because [`l3regex` has been folded into the kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491456/59078) and you have copied code from elsewhere that uses `\__scan_new:N`.

In the [documentation for LaTeX3 Interfaces](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), this command has been replaced by `\scan_new:N`, and a simple renaming should resolve this error. Furthermore, remove `\usepackage{l3regex}` from your document (if it is present and somehow your document is compiling).