# Input sanitization for \fp_eval

Tags: expl3, latex3, floating-point

Is there a command that asks whether an argument to `\fp_eval` is a parse error or not? E.g.:

```
\fp_if_valid:nTF { 1+2.3*2 } { yes } { no } % yes
\fp_if_valid:nTF { 1+2.3*  } { yes } { no } % no
```

I would like to be able to sanitize user input and throw my own error if their input is not valid. Anyways I was just curious whether there is a built-in command to do this, or whether the latex3 team intends to add this functionality. I wrote the following code, which seems to work
(thanks to Rob Hall for fixing some mistakes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Add missing variant based on definition of \exp_last_unbraced:Nf in l3expan.dtx    
\cs_set:Npn \exp_last_unbraced:NNf #1#2#3
    { \exp_after:wN #1 \exp_after:wN #2 \exp:w \exp_end_continue_f:w #3 }

\tl_new:N \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl

% \return_marker: for maintaining true/false state outside \fp_eval program flow
\scan_new:N \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker:
% Protected wrappers for \prg_return_true: and \prg_return_false:
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_return_true:  { \prg_return_true:  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_return_false: { \prg_return_false: }

% Replace "\return_marker: \return_<true or false>:" 
% with "\return_marker: \return_false:"
\cs_new:Npn \my_fp_if_valid_set_return_false:wN #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: #2
    { #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: \my_fp_if_valid_return_false: }

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \my_fp_if_valid:n {T, F, TF} {
    \group_begin:
        % make error command throw away error message and call \set_return_false:wN
        \cs_set:Nn \__msg_expandable_error:n { \my_fp_if_valid_set_return_false:wN }
        % Sets \l_if_valid_tl to 
        % "<numerical result> \return_marker: \return_<true or false>:"
        \tl_set:Nx \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl { 
            \fp_eval:n { #1 } 
            \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: \my_fp_if_valid_return_true:
        }
    % Put <numerical result> into \result: and evaluate \return_<true or false>:
    \exp_last_unbraced:NNf \group_end:
        \my_fp_if_valid_helper:w \tl_use:N \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl
}

% Put <numerical result> into \result:
\cs_new:Npn \my_fp_if_valid_helper:w #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: {
    \cs_set:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_result: { #1 }
} 

\cs_new_eq:NN \fpifvalid \my_fp_if_valid:nTF

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\testfpifvalid#1{\fpifvalid{#1}{\color{blue}}{\color{red}}\texttt{#1}\par}
\begin{document}

\testfpifvalid{1+1}             % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+}              % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3*2}         % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3 2}         % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3.*2}        % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1++2}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+*2}            % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1*+2}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1/0}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1)2}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1(2}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1(2)}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+1(2/6)+sin(7)} % valid
\testfpifvalid{floor(6,-1)}     % valid
\testfpifvalid{floor(6,7,7)}    % invalid

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should name them differently, at least, by using your own prefix and probably `xparse` to provide the document-level interface.

Comment: @cfr I agree with the name them differently suggestion, updated to add `my_` prefix to everything.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `xparse` instead of performing a `\let` (or maybe a `\def` wrapper, in case the definition of the inner command might change). The point of `xparse` is to handle complicated argument syntax. If my argument syntax is just that I want a single manditory short argument, what's the benefit?

Comment: Really, my point was you shouldn't use `\cs_new_eq` with a function name not in line with the naming. But you are handling input: you are providing `\fpifvalid` which takes 3 arguments. The point of `xparse`, as I understand it, is to provide document-level macros (at least in cases which one or more arguments are or may be involved). That is, it is not just for more complicated cases, it is for simple and complicated cases which expose expl3 functions at the document-level. (& of course there are good reasons to avoid `\let`, `\def`, though `\let` sometimes seems most suitable for variables?)

Comment: I want a function `\fpfifvalid` that takes three mandatory arguments, the first short, the other two long. `\fp_if_valid:nTF` takes three mandatory arguments, the first short, the other two long. Why do I need a fancy package for this? Also, `\cs_new_eq:NN` is just a variant of `\let` that does an existence safety check, and `\cs_new:Npn` is a version of `\def` that does an existence check.

Comment: @HoodChatham The point is to keep the programming clean. `expl3` is for programming (and the naming conventions should be followed), `xparse` is for document commands (and those naming conventions do not apply). (This is similar to how you should use `\tl_new:N` even though you don't need to, or how you should use `v` and not `o` for expanding token list variables. It just makes everything so much tidyer.) Just do `\NewDocumentCommand\fpifvalid{}{\my_fp_if_valid:nTF}`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question in 2020 having this same need. I am unaware (like OP) if there is some other canned solution in the LaTeX3 Interfaces at this time. If you want to use this approach, there are issues to be addressed:

1. Some minor typo's in OPs example code need to be resolved
2. [`\__scan_new:N` has been relocated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541755/59078)

For those looking for a copy-paste drop-in solution using OPs code, take the following

```
% depends on xfp, pgfmath
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Add missing variant based on definition of \exp_last_unbraced:Nf in l3expan.dtx    
\cs_set:Npn \exp_last_unbraced:NNf #1#2#3
    { \exp_after:wN #1 \exp_after:wN #2 \exp:w \exp_end_continue_f:w #3 }

\tl_new:N \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl

% \return_marker: for maintaining true/false state outside \fp_eval program flow
\scan_new:N \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker:
% Protected wrappers for \prg_return_true: and \prg_return_false:
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_return_true:  { \prg_return_true:  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_return_false: { \prg_return_false: }

% Replace "\return_marker: \return_<true or false>:" 
% with "\return_marker: \return_false:"
\cs_new:Npn \my_fp_if_valid_set_return_false:wN #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: #2
    { #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: \my_fp_if_valid_return_false: }

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \my_fp_if_valid:n {T, F, TF} {
    \group_begin:
        % make error command throw away error message and call \set_return_false:wN
        \cs_set:Nn \__msg_expandable_error:n { \my_fp_if_valid_set_return_false:wN }
        % Sets \l_if_valid_tl to 
        % "<numerical result> \return_marker: \return_<true or false>:"
        \tl_set:Nx \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl { 
            \fp_eval:n { #1 } 
            \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: \my_fp_if_valid_return_true:
        }
    % Put <numerical result> into \result: and evaluate \return_<true or false>:
    \exp_last_unbraced:NNf \group_end:
        \my_fp_if_valid_helper:w \tl_use:N \l_my_fp_if_valid_tl
}

% Put <numerical result> into \result:
\cs_new:Npn \my_fp_if_valid_helper:w #1 \my_fp_if_valid_return_marker: {
    \cs_set:Nn \my_fp_if_valid_result: { #1 }
} 

\cs_new_eq:NN \fpifvalid \my_fp_if_valid:nTF

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

OPs original demonstration will now continue to work

```
% demo depends on xcolor
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\testfpifvalid#1{\fpifvalid{#1}{\color{blue}}{\color{red}}\texttt{#1}\par}
\testfpifvalid{1+1}             % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+}              % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3*2}         % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3 2}         % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+2.3.*2}        % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1++2}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+*2}            % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1*+2}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1/0}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1)2}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1(2}             % invalid
\testfpifvalid{1(2)}            % valid
\testfpifvalid{1+1(2/6)+sin(7)} % valid
\testfpifvalid{floor(6,-1)}     % valid
\testfpifvalid{floor(6,7,7)}    % invalid
```

Comment: The `pgfmath` include seems irrelevant. I suspect that I was writing this at the same time as I made similar code for `\pgfmathparse` redefining the error commands to escape out of parsing and return false. Unfortunately, life is much harder for the etex built-in `\numexpr` and for `\int_eval` which is a wrapper around `\numexpr`. I had to write a whole finite state machine to sanitize input for `\numexpr`.

Comment: Do you mind if I copy your fixed version back into my post?

Comment: Not at all. That's really the reference people are going to see first, anyway