# 'l3regex.sty' not found

Tags: preamble, l3regex

I updated my MiKTeX today. Now, I do not get any error without packages but it can not compile my latex files with packages.

Uninstalling and reinstalling both Texmaker and Miktex did not work. I could not find l3regex.sty file on internet.

> LaTeX Error: File `l3regex.sty' not found.

**My packages:**

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor  = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = red]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }  
\usepackage{coloring}  
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Comment: Update MikTeX in both admin *and* user mode. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Comment: I think there was a change to how `l3regex` was distributed a while ago. If I understand correctly it should be part of `expl3.sty` which should be installed by MikTeX's `l3kernel` package. So you should make sure that `l3kernel` is installed an up to date. I assume, though, that the real culprit is an older version of a different package that tries to use the old name to load the module. If the full update in both modes does not help, please try to prepare a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and upload the full `.log` file to a text-sharing website (e.g. pastebin)

Comment: Aha! https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468973/35864 mentions changes in the distribution of `l3regex`.

Comment: Any news here? Could you fix your issue?

Comment: I just had the same error when compiling nox's solution that was working a year ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442654/138900

Comment: @AndréC `l3regex` has been integrated into the kernel. For documents explicitly loading `l3regex` it should be enough not to load it (make sure that at least `expl3` or `xparse` is loaded). In the code you link, just change `\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}` to `\usepackage{xparse}`. But with the preamble shown in *this* question it is much more likely that not all involved packages were updated correctly (the classic MikTeX update in Admin and User mode issue).

Comment: If this question was to be reopened it should be closed as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468973/35864

Comment: @moewe Agreed: done

Comment: @moewe It would have been clearer to turn your comment into a answer.

Comment: @JosephWright  It would have been clearer to turn the moewe comment into a answer.

Comment: @AndréC That would be an answer _on the question I've duped to_: the entire point of marking-as-dupe is to avoid answers spread out all over the place

Comment: @JosephWright The title of the other question is not identical and your answer is not identical to moewe's comment that explains that it is enough to load `xparse` without loading `l3regex.sty`

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem by adding this in preamble:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3regex.sty\endcsname{}
```

Comment: Just to make other people aware of this. This is also the workaround proposed by Joseph in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468975/35864. It will pretend that the package `l3regex` has been loaded (the package was merged into the `expl3` kernel so need not be loaded separately any more). Most packages should have been updated to use the new syntax. But if you are stuck with code that can't be updated for some reason this might be reasonable.